# Excel VBA multi-chechbox control on userform

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I'm confused about checkbox controls on userforms. I have to control the values of all checkboxes in my form and take actions depending on the values.For example, 
If cb(checkbox) 1,2 and 3 are True then excel will do action A.
If cb 2,4 and 5 are True then excel will do action B
and so on...

[image]

How can I control multiple checkbox values without so many if statements?

Comment: You will have to use If statements or Select...Case statements to process depending upon what the checkboxes do. What do the checkboxes actually do?

Comment: @AndyW they are only for the control purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could go with the following kind of pseudocode:

```
With Me
    Select Case True
        Case .CheckBox1 And .CheckBox2 And .CheckBox3
            ' action A
        Case .CheckBox2 And .CheckBox4 And .CheckBox5
            ' action B
        Case ... ' other cases
            ' corresponding action

        Case Else ' if no preceeding cases are met
            ' default action
End With
```

Comment: That's awesome!  I had no idea you could do that.

Comment: @user3598756 Is it possible to put more control cases inside the "Case" blocks?

Comment: @merterino, yes, act as I already showed you in the pseudocode: the pattern ` Case ... ' other cases\ ' corresponding action` can be replicated as many times as you need